# Why do the values initialised in a parents class disappear from a treemap in a child class

Tags: java, swing, treemap

```
public class Methods extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Method_Interface {

    protected Map<String, User> userMap = new TreeMap<>();
    protected String username, password;
    protected boolean loggedIn;

    public void fillUserMap() {        
         //Some code:
    }    
}
```

Code for initializing values to the MAP:

```
public void fillUserMap() {

        String race = "";
        String month, gender;
        int m, age, day, year;    

        for (Forms.Users u : usersList) {    
            month = "";
            gender = "";    
            switch (u.getGender()) {    
                case 0:
                    gender = "Male";    
                    break;    
                case 1:
                    gender = "Female";    
                    break;    
            }

            switch (u.getRace()) {    
                case 0:
                    race = "White";    
                    break;    
                case 1:
                    race = "Black";    
                    break;    
                case 2:
                    race = "Coloured";    
                    break;    
                case 3:
                    race = "Indian";    
                    break;    
                case 4:
                    race = "Other";    
            }

            day = Integer.parseInt(u.getDateOfBirth().trim().substring(0, 2));
            year = Integer.parseInt(u.getDateOfBirth().trim().substring(6, 10));    
            age = 2014 - year;    
            m = Integer.parseInt(u.getDateOfBirth().trim().substring(3, 5));    

            switch (m) {    
                case 1:
                    month = "January";    
                    break;    
                case 2:
                    month = "February";    
                    break;    
                case 3:
                    month = "March";    
                    break;    
                case 4:
                    month = "April";    
                    break;    
                case 5:
                    month = "May";    
                    break;    
                case 6:
                    month = "June";    
                    break;    
                case 7:
                    month = "July";    
                    break;    
                case 8:
                    month = "August";    
                    break;    
                case 9:
                    month = "September";    
                    break;    
                case 10:
                    month = "October";    
                    break;    
                case 11:
                    month = "November";    
                    break;    
                case 12:
                    month = "December";    
                    break;    
            }

            if (u.getUserid().substring(0, 2).equals("#D")) {                    
            try{                    
                int get = donorInfoList.indexOf(u.getUserid());
                get++;
                DonorInfo d = donorInfoList.get(get);    
                Blood_Donor temp = new Blood_Donor(bloodType(u), d.getTimesDonated().toString(), u.getWeight(), u.getUserid(), u.getPassword(), u.getFirstname(), u.getSurname(), day, month, year, u.getEmail(), gender, race, age);

                for (DonorInfo dTemp : donorInfoList) {    
                    if (dTemp.getUserid().equals(u.getUserid())) {    
                        temp.setWeight(u.getWeight());
                        temp.setUnits(dTemp.getTimesDonated().toString());
                        temp.setBloodType(bloodType(u));    
                        userMap.put(temp.getuName(), temp);    
                    }

                }

            } catch(Exception e) {                        
                    System.out.println(e);
                }    
            } else if (u.getUserid().substring(0, 2).equals("#C")) {

                int get = clientsList.indexOf(u.getUserid()+1);
                Clients c = clientsList.get(get);                    
                Client temp = new Client(c.getDebt(), u.getWeight(), bloodType(u), u.getUserid(), u.getPassword(), u.getFirstname(), u.getSurname(), day, month, year, u.getEmail(), gender, race, age);

                for (Clients cTemp : clientsList) {    
                    Map<Integer, String> products = new TreeMap<>();    
                    if (cTemp.getClientsPK().getUserid().equals(u.getUserid())) {    
                        for (Clients cTemp2 : clientsList) {    
                            int i = 0;    
                            if (cTemp2.getClientsPK().getUserid().equalsIgnoreCase(u.getUserid())) {    
                                for (int j = 0; j < cTemp2.getQuantity(); j++) {    
                                    if (cTemp2.getQuantity() == 1) {    
                                        products.put(i++, cTemp2.getClientsPK().getProductId());    
                                        break;    
                                    } else {    
                                        products.put(i++, cTemp2.getClientsPK().getProductId());    
                                    }    
                                }    
                            }    
                        }    
                        temp.setProducts(products);    
                        userMap.put(temp.getuName(), temp);    
                    }    
                }    
            } else if (u.getUserid().substring(0, 2).equals("#S")) {

                User temp = new User(u.getUserid(), u.getPassword(), u.getFirstname(), u.getSurname(), day, month, year, u.getEmail(), gender, race, age);    
                userMap.put(u.getUserid(), temp);    
            }    
        }    
    }
```

Child JFrame:

```
public final class Log_In extends Methods {    
    //some code    
}
```

I run the fillUserMap method in the parent JFrame i.e Methods before trying to get those values back in one of my child JFrames. But when I search for values in my treemap I dont find any

Comment: I get the same values at instantiation and initialization of the values in the treeMap but get a different value in the child class however I only initialize the map in the parents as seen above.

Comment: I declared the treemap as final but I still have the same situation

Comment: If you don't post the code, we can't find the bug.

Comment: Your problem doesn't so far appear to be related to Swing. Therefore I warmly suggest you write a minimal example which reproduces your problem and doesn't involve Swing classes. In the very unlikely case that by then you haven't already figured out the solution yourself, update your question with that code.

Comment: You declared a method fillUserMap(), but your code doesn't call it anywhere. It's still partial, and mostly irrelevant code, so we still have to guess.

Comment: Assuming `getGender()` return a String, look at your switch `switch (u.getGender()) {`, and the cases you are check for are integers `case 0:`. Same with the `getRace()` switch. You want to do a little more research on how to use switch statements. You cases should match what you have in the parenthesis of the switch. On the other hand, this seems like a compete [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: On a side note: Make your methods smaller and more manageable. Split different responsibilities up into different methods. This will make your methods more manageable, testable, and readable and a whole lot easier to debug

Comment: Thanks guys. Its okay though I solved the problem